# How to add additional targets in PCL visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I need to add xamarin.android but I have it installed but I can see it like a target, please can any help me.
[targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGvBn.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Open the visual studio 2017 installer.  Press the modify button.  Make sure the Mobile Development with .Net workflow is selected.  The extra targets will be added with the installation of Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Every modification about extensions in VS 2017 must to do in installer.

1 - Open the VS Installer

2 - CLick in button Modify

3 - you will see lot of options, just find Developmento mobile with .NET

4 - Select Item and click modify

Wait until the installation to be complete.

That's It

Comment: well I have the problem that it is installed, sorry I am new in stackoverflow, I have a image of this but i don't know how add it.

Answer (score 0):

well I resolve this, the problem was that I install visual studio in disk D, because disk C is a ssd 100Gb so some things install in C and anothers in D, then I reinstall windows and visual studio. Now is working.